# Editing css for magento 2 extension, how to take effect?

Tags: magento2, css

I installed a extension (bannerslider), all css seems placed in `app/code/Magestore/Bannerslider/view/frontend/web/css`

i had tried to delete all css in this folder then run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy zh_Hant_TW
```

or

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

but nothing were changed in frontend, anyone knows how to edit css of a extension?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to make a folder in my theme so Vendor/Theme/Magestore_Bannerslider/web/css copy the files in there and then modify to your needs. Your delpoy steps followed by clearing any cache if enabled should then overwrite the CSS for that module.

I would also make sure cache is cleared on your web browser as these can get cached locally. If it's less files that have been modified these need to be compiled, when using development mode I just turn on client side compilation from within admin.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not delete css web/css and try these steps

1- `rm -rf var/*`

2- `rm -rf pub/static/*`

3- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

4- `chmod -R 777 var pub/static`

Comment: it works after delete the related file in pub/static, but need to do this everytime to change a little bit css? it is so inconvenient